# Stop subsequent queries in apollo after 401 has been returned?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using apollo client to make a query in my Component. It is composed with 2 queries. How do i stop it from sending another query to it after it has given me a 401 error. I am using a onError Apollo Link Error to listen for errors. However it dispatches both queries and i cannot stop the next one.

Answer (score 3):

Apollo Link Error allows you to intercept and handle query or network errors. It doesn't however provide an opportunity to manage subsequent requests. For this you will need to create your own link.

I've used something like the following in the past. The example below specifically handles bearer auth with refresh tokens but the same principle could be used to handle any auth failure.

```js
import { ApolloLink, Observable } from 'apollo-link';

const isAuthError = (statusCode: number) => [401, 403].includes(statusCode);

const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // Set outgoing Authorization headers
  const setHeaders = () =>
    operation.setContext(({ store, headers, ...rest }) => {
       // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
       const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
       // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them

      return {
        ...rest,
        store,
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      };
    });

  setHeaders();

  return new Observable(obs => {
    const subscriber = {
      next: obs.next.bind(obs),
      // Handle auth errors. Only network or runtime errors appear here.
      error: error => {
        if (isAuthError(error.statusCode)) {
          // Trigger an auth refresh.
                refreshTokenOrLogin()
                  .then(setHeaders)
                  .then(() => forward(operation).subscribe(subscriber));
              }
            }
          });
        } else {
          obs.error(error);
        }
      },
      complete: obs.complete.bind(obs)
    };

    forward(operation).subscribe(subscriber);
  });
});
```

The first portion sets the auth context as documented by [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html#Header). You should replace this with whichever auth mechanism you are using.

```js
operation.setContext(({ store, headers, ...rest }) => {
   // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
   const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
   // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them

  return {
    ...rest,
    store,
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  };
});
```

Non terminating links like this must return an observable. This allows us to catch any network errors just as Apollo Link Error does except we can now handle what happens subsequently. In this case we create and return a new observable with an error handler that will trigger an auth token refresh and then retry the request. The next and completion handlers are passed through to the next link untouched.

```js
new Observable(obs => {
    const subscriber = {
      next: obs.next.bind(obs),
      // Handle auth errors. Only network or runtime errors appear here.
      error: error => {
        if (isAuthError(error.statusCode)) {
          // Trigger an auth refresh.
                refreshTokenOrLogin()
                  .then(setHeaders)
                  .then(() => 
                    // We can now retry the request following a successful token refresh.
                    forward(operation).subscribe(subscriber)
                  );
              }
            }
          });
        } else {
          obs.error(error);
        }
      },
      complete: obs.complete.bind(obs)
    };

    forward(operation).subscribe(subscriber);
  });
```

It might be easier to think of this as 2 links. One that sets the outgoing auth context and the other that captures the response and handles the auth errors.

Comment: What happens if you have two almost-simultaneous requests with auth error? Would it trigger multiple token refreshes in a race condition?